# Docker copy composer vendor from inside container

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, composer-php

I've made a container which I am building through `docker-compose`, here is `.yml`:

```
  gateway:
    build: .
    image: sng
    container_name: sng
    command: tail -F /dev/null
    ports:
      - "10091:10091"
    volumes:
      - vendor:/root/vendor

volumes:
  vendor:
```

And `Dockerfile` is simply pulling the image and running `composer install`:

```
FROM php:7-fpm-alpine

EXPOSE 10091
WORKDIR /root
COPY . .

RUN apk add composer && composer install --no-progress
```

Is there a way for me to sync back the created `vendor` folder automatically back to the codebase without running a `docker cp` from the host machine?

Answer (score 0):

Oh man, im so sorry!! I did what you want, is just mount a volume of vendor to the vendor folder.

```
volumes: 
- path/to/local/vendor:vendor
```

Comment: Read the last sentence once again please ;)